# Google hangout API for Android

Tags: android

Any idea on how you can integrate Google hangout in an Android App ? I do not see any API that is currently available. Is using WebView an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't anything at the moment and I don't believe a WebView version will work, because hangouts needs the camera plugin that googles installs and it's not available on mobile browsers.

[start google hangouts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127051/start-google-hangouts-in-android)

[How can I start a Google Hangout in Android with an Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203364/how-can-i-start-a-google-hangout-in-android-with-an-intent)

Answer (score 0):

From [**Hangouts API Reference**](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/):

> The Hangouts API provides the programming interface to Hangouts video calls. It provides a JavaScript interface that enables your app to do such things as list the Hangout participants, share data between instances of your app in the Hangout, control some aspects of the user interface, and control the microphone, camera and speaker settings.[...]

Answer (score 0):

> The new Hangouts API will allow developers to build their own experiences inside Hangouts and build real-time applications that use Hangouts, similar to Google’s own built-in YouTube player. The YouTube player lets Google+ users in a Hangout watch videos together at the same time.
>
> **Google also announced screen-sharing, Google Docs editing and sketching as new built-in features for Google+ Hangouts today, thereby forcing developers to think beyond the obvious integrations to more creative uses of the Hangouts API when building their apps.**

See more at http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/20/google-launches-hangouts-api-for-developers/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DanGetz tanx dear for correction in future i will try and i am going to add in this answer :)