# Android Google Hangout Automate Call shortcut and Answer

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, google-hangouts, tasker

I like the quality of Google Hangout video calls.  Would like to setup for my mother on her tablet so that she can hit a shortcut button, initiate a google video call to me AND when receiving a video call, automatically answer.

I have found some discussion about creating a tasker shortcut, but can't figure out the right intent for both direct dial and profile.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579228/start-google-hangout-from-intent-in-new-hangouts-android-app