# How to open hangout app with recepient and hangout text set from our app in android

Tags: android, google-hangouts

1. I have an android app with two editText and a button.
2. In one editText user enters a emailId and in another editText user enters the text to be sent as hangout.
3. When user presses a button i need to open a hangout app with hangout recepient set to the email Id user entered in above step and with hangout text set to the text user entered in above step.

   Can i achieve this using intents..can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Comment: have you do any thing except make edittext and button ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start Google Hangout from Intent in New Hangouts Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579228/start-google-hangout-from-intent-in-new-hangouts-android-app)

Comment: no............ @Duggu

Comment: Its opening hangout but it is not setting the recepient.@2Dee

Comment: @Harish.N means you want spoon feeding???

Comment: I mean i'am not doing any UI thing except editText and a button. I searched about how to open hangouts.. I'am able to open hangout and set the text to be sent but i'am not able to set the recepient @Duggu