# How can I create an intent in my app to send a message through Hangouts and Yahoo Messenger?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-hangouts, yahoo-messenger

I am trying to create two separate buttons and separate intents to send a message through Hangouts and through Yahoo Messenger. Is there a way to open the chat window for a certain user if I know the user's id and email? I did this for Facebook Messenger using

```
Uri fbUri = Uri.parse("fb://messaging/" + userid);
    Intent fbIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fbUri);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hangout is not possible to open directly. Check link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579228/start-google-hangout-from-intent-in-new-hangouts-android-app

Comment: Yes I found out somewhere that it will not be possible to do this for Hangouts. But I would really like to make Yahoo Messenger work. I found this:

Uri yahooUri = Uri.parse("ymsgr:sendim?" + username);

But it is not working, it is crashing the app with a message:



No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=ymsgr:sendim?someusername}