# Start hangouts call from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-hangouts

In my application i want to add possibility to Start a call hangouts

It is possible to call intent hangout application with an extra email google to call this person ?

What i want to do it is something like this:

```
     Intent sky = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    
    Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/mail_to_call@gmail.com"));
    startActivity(sky);
```

So when i excecute this i want to call person with mail mail_to_call@gmail.com throught hangout application

any help will be welcomed

Comment: Please rephrase the question to aid in understanding.

Comment: It is better now ? :)

Comment: Please expand on this: "with an extra email google to call this person"

Comment: Actually, what would be VERY helpful, is for you to write out the workflow you expect in your application... what should happen at what point in execution. Not only would it help us to help you, but it might reduce your need to have other help at all.

Comment: And now :) ? it is clear ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579228/start-google-hangout-from-intent-in-new-hangouts-android-app

Comment: and https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/starting-a-hangout-from-an-android-app