# How to navigate to Hangouts chat from android application

Tags: android, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I want to navigate from my android app to hangouts text messages chat.
i already have the google user/ id of the user i would like to chat with, but i found only video hangouts api examples.
is it possible at all? 
thank you very much.

Comment: use intent to open hangout chat from android.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan
i know how to just open hangouts in new activity , my purpose is to open it on specific chat - with the user name/id that i already have

Comment: username / id ?? are you reffering to the email account configured in hangout or something else like mobile number.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yeah i meant to open the relevant chat by email account, sorry i didnt mention clearly

Answer (score 1):

If you're opening it with any conversation number, try to write code like this:

```
            String number = "9876543210"

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            i.setPackage("com.google.android.talk");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible to open the Hangout chat for a specific contact through Android Intent.**

We are allowed to open the hangout app and it displays the contacts for us. After picking contacts, we could able to send message / share text with that particular contact.

check this [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579228/start-google-hangout-from-intent-in-new-hangouts-android-app)

To open hangout chat directly without user to pick from the listed apps, below code will help you,

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
    share.setPackage("com.google.android.talk");  // open hangouts app directly
    startActivity(share);
```

Happy Coding..!! :) :)