# what intents or apis does Google's Duo app for Android support?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-duo

Can we start a new video call via Google Duo via intent?
Can we launch into any specific screen within the app?

We currently have support for launching Hangouts from our app, and we would like to add Duo support as well.

Comment: did you got anything for above question

Comment: I wish someone would answer this. Also, could you tell me how you went about launching Hangouts from your app? I'm having the hardest time figuring out what data to send in the intent so that Hangouts will call a certain contact. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RustWebDev we're actually not initiating a call, just opening the hangouts chat screen with a specific contact, we're using a method similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38674136/819355, also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35983348/819355

Comment: @marmor I'm curious, I want to build hangouts integration but can't find any recent examples - do you have something that's still working?

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the truecaller source code. Can't get to work, but hope it helps. I'm using Kotlin.

```
val I = Intent("com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.CALL")
i.'package' = "com.google.android.apps.tachyon"
i.data = Uri.parse("tel: $phone") // phone is the phone number your to a function
i.putExtra(com.google.android.apps.tachyon.extra.IS_AUDIO_ONLY, false)
startActivity(i)
```

Comment: interesting, thanks, looks like there's a typo in the first line, probably should be "tachyon.action.CALL" instead of with 'tachyo'

Comment: Is `com.google.android.apps.tachyon.extra.IS_AUDIO_ONLY` a string? Meaning it's supposed to be `"com.google.android.apps.tachyon.extra.IS_AUDIO_ONLY"` ? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.tachyon");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm not looking into just opening the Google Duo app, i want deep linking into it, e.g. opening the conversation screen with a specific contact. We have such integration with Hangouts, Whatsapp, Facebook and many other apps, but not currently for Duo

Comment: did you find the answer?