# Start video call in Hangouts or Duo using intent?

Tags: android, google-hangouts, google-duo

I am looking for a way to start a video call in either Hangouts or Duo.
There seems to be 0 documentation regarding what intents should be used.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider **Duo** here.

### Research

1.First of all, to find out the intent, you should activate the USB debug mode on your phone - please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android) to find out how to do it.

2.Then, connect your phone to your computer so that you could see the **logcat** from your device (debug level should be info).

3.Open **Contacts**(from Google) and find a contact to whom you can call using **Duo**. Now, start the call and search for *com.google.android.apps.tachyon*. There will be a couple of matches but the important one looks something like:

> START u0 {act=com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.CALL typ=null flg=0x0 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.tachyon/com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ExternalCallActivity}} from uid 10031

4.So, once you know the component info for your **Duo** app, just add the following code in your app from where you'd like to start a video call.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setAction("com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.CALL")
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.tachyon",
    "com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ExternalCallActivity")
startActivity(intent)
```

5.You'll see a video call screen with possible contacts.

### Conclusion

If you'd like to find out how to start a video call or chat or something else, try to do the same as above - do it manually first and check what intents (and arguments) are used in those cases.

Comment: For me this results in a new activity of type `com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.PRECALL_ACTIVITY` being fired, while calling from the dialer results in a new activity of type `com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.CALL` being fired. Both have class name of `com.google.android.apps.tachyon/.ProcessedCallRequestActivity`. The manual activity firing attempt results in a pre-call screen with the correct contact and a 'Video Call' button, while the dialer's intent successfully starts a video call. The intents look the same in logcat. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any API documentation available for google duo app integration right now.

You can use this code it's working for starting a duo call.

```
String data = "content://com.android.contacts/data/" + ID;
// Build the intent
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
// the _ids you save goes here at the end of /data/id
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + ID));
//For audio call
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, "com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsAudioActionActivity"));
//use this for video call
//intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, "com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsVideoActionActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
// Verify it resolves
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
// Start an activity if it's safe
if (isIntentSafe) {
    context.startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Opening Duo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Or You can use following approach passing telephone number

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.tachyon");
intent.setAction("com.google.android.apps.tachyon.action.CALL");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

A) `HangoutUrlHandlerActivity`, `ShortlinkUrlHandlerActivity` and `ConversationUrlHandlerActivity` are available for receiving `Intent` with an `Uri`.

What I have so far, which is actually working, but only for *ongoing* conversations & video calls:

a) opening an ongoing conversation:

```
void joinConversation(@NonNull String conversationId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("hangouts.google.com").appendPath("chat").appendPath(conversationId).build();
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.talk", "com.google.android.apps.hangouts.phone.ConversationUrlHandlerActivity");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.google.android.hangouts/vnd.google.android.hangout_whitelist");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

b) joining an ongoing video call (the ID comes from [hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/meet](https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/meet/)):

```
void joinHangout(@NonNull String callId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("g.co").appendPath("hangout").appendPath(Uri.encode(callId)).build();
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.talk", "com.google.android.apps.hangouts.phone.ShortlinkUrlHandlerActivity");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.google.android.hangouts/vnd.google.android.hangout_whitelist");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If direct invites should not be possible - one could still schedule calls through the Calendar API, where one gets the `callId` from, so that one can join the Hangout once it is scheduled. Google [Meet](https://meet.google.com/_meet) does not even support direct invites, but only through Google Calendar appointments.

---

Based upon the comment from @[Mir Milad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1162154), I've managed to at least create a new text conversation; but still nothing that would ring someone up (it notifies as soon as the first message had been sent):

```
/** @param googleUserId that 21 digit Google user ID, aka Gaia ID  */
void createConversation(@NonNull String googleUserId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("hangouts.google.com").appendPath("chat").appendPath("person").appendPath(googleUserId).build();
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.talk", "com.google.android.apps.hangouts.phone.ConversationUrlHandlerActivity");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.google.android.hangouts/vnd.google.android.hangout_whitelist");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

As far as I can tell, there is no such thing as an explicit "call me" URL for Hangouts. And even web-based, the Hangout is being initiated with two Gaia ID, which then result in a room name to join. Even Google's own [Hangouts Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer) seems to be broken, when looking at the recent comments.

---

B) For Google Duo, this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925337/what-intents-or-apis-does-googles-duo-app-for-android-support).

Comment: The question here is about looking for a way to START a video call, NOT to join an ongoing one. You answer is misleading! I should have down-voted you, but I won't do something awful like you did to some other people here.

Comment: @harrytmthy It is barely misleading, when it explicitly states it... in case one would read. This at least makes it clear, that one cannot directly video-call - except there is an URL which would do so. Being down-voted for providing original content is questionable, since it took me quite a while to find these intents and URL arguments. This question are actually **two** questions, not one.