# Making a Video call using Hangout api

Tags: android, video, skype, hangouts-api

Hello i have an android application , in which i want a video chat functionality ,
i searched a lot on internet but couldnot find any working and simple solution to this , then i found hangout api ,

now i want to add hangout video call feature to my own application but i cannot find where to get started .

All i want is from my own android application i want to initiate any third party application for video call . and get back to my own application when video call is done

how can i acheive this ?

i have my application codes , but sharing them here will make it complex , any guide to get started , i shall be thankfull

Comment: apprtc can be used for that

Comment: i tried one of the rtc app provided by pubnub but building their project stucks me at connecting and does not move ahead

Comment: I am talkign about https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo

Comment: @Doe i am getting this error “Peerconnection factory is not created”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may would like to try [AppRTC](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo)

### Getting Room ID

```
roomConnectionParameters = new RoomConnectionParameters(roomUri.toString(), roomId, loopback);
```

### Setting Fragment Call

```
callFragment.setArguments(intent.getExtras());
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.call_fragment_container, callFragment);
ft.add(R.id.hud_fragment_container, hudFragment);
ft.commit();
```

### Connecting to Peer

```
peerConnectionClient = PeerConnectionClient.getInstance();
    if (loopback) {
      PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
      options.networkIgnoreMask = 0;
      peerConnectionClient.setPeerConnectionFactoryOptions(options);
}
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664864/add-dial-receive-signalling-mechanism-for-apprtcdemo-at-client-side Kindly check this question

Comment: @Addi.Star heheh smart ass :D .. I will try When I have time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to start a video Hangouts call. The closest you can do is open up a conversation with the person via an Intent.

[Intent to open conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961376/5063104)

[Source to show feature doesn't currently exist](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=385)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Google Hangouts API will no longer be available soon. See here for details: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq

As an alternative, [Vidyo.io](https://vidyo.io) provides mobile SDK support for Android to build a multiparty video chat app. Check out this [howto video](https://vidyo.io/how-to/build-mobile-video-chat-app-android-minutes/) that steps through building a video chat app in Android Studio.

Full disclosure: I work for Vidyo.