# Add dial/receive signalling mechanism for AppRTCDemo at client side

Tags: android, webrtc, apprtcdemo

Hi I am using AppRTCDemo and its working on their server. How ever the current mechanism is for exchanging chat-rooms name and entering the same room connects the peers.

But I want to dial a call from one device to receive a call from other device and then peers should enter a room for video session ,

I have searched a lot , I have come up with for that I need signalling-server which I don't have and don't want to put hands on it ,

Now in this situation how can the other device know that device one is dialing and sharing particular room name to accept and enter the same room for video call at client side in Android .

https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo

Comment: @Maveň I think the question title should be **How to share `roomID` to another user to whom you want to get conected**. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two android apk available for **WebRTC**, `appRtcDemo` and `webRtcDemo`. `appRtcDemo` apk can be used for android device to browser connectivity. You need to provide room id to connect to one room. If you are the room initiator then you have to enter -1.
If you want to connect two android device then you have to compile and install `webRtcDemo` apk. This apk interface provide place to enter ip address of another device and vice versa then both device will be connected.

Please go through -> http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started

For more information. Both the apks i've compiled and installed and checked how it works.

I was able to make calls successfully between two android device using webrtcdemo. But I tested using WLAN of my office network. I did not use it further because I was using apprtcdemo for app reference. My suggestion is when you enter remote ip in webrtcdemo,just check if loop-back is unchecked. I guess for you loop-back is enabled, so you are receiving your own video packet, though you have entered remote ip. Make sure loop-back is disabled while making call.